write a powershell script to start a few projects as "start without debugging" in VS2022
I would like to write a powershell script that start a given set of VS projects as if I run "Start without debugging" inside VS2022 for each of those projects. How may I do that?

Assuming it's .NET project, probably have a look at dotnet run

If you want to build a few VS projects with powershell scripts, you can use msbuild or devenv command. Please check  the following sample:
devenv mysln.sln /build
MSBuild.exemysln.sln

Build a VS project
# your msbuild installation path(different in your machine)
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
$projectFileAbsPath = "your project path"
& $msbuild $projectFileAbsPath

Build a few VS projects(use foreach to iterate )
# your msbuild installation path(different in your machine)
$msbuild = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
$projectFileAbsPath = "your project file path"
$baseDirectory = "your base directory"
# put your projects file path in .txt file
$solutionFilesPath = "$baseDirectory\SolutionConfig.txt"
# get project file path
$projectFiles = Get-Content $solutionFilesPath 
foreach($projectFile in $projectFiles){
Write-Output $projectFile
# c# 
if ($projectFile.EndsWith(".sln")) 
    {
        $projectFileAbsPath = "$projectFile"
        Write-Output "project file"  $projectFileAbsPath
        & $msbuild $projectFileAbsPath
     }
}

Docs referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/devenv-command-line-switches?view=vs-2022
Hope it can help you.

Thanks. Is there a command like devnev run /nodebug myproj.csproj?

Yes, you can use dotnet run mentioned by Daniel in the comment or MSBuild command  .
